# Creating a single definition for generic type parameters

Tags: java, generics, types, parameters

If I have many methods that use the same generic type parameters, is there a way to define those generic type parameters only once? For example, if I have methods like this:

```
public static <T extends A & B> void method1() {}
public static <T extends A & B> void method2() {}
```

Is there a way to define them as something like this:

```
GenericType = <T extends A & B>;
public static <GenericType> void method1() {}
public static <GenericType> void method2() {}
```

I've done a lot of Googling and can't find an answer on this; it seems like something that we should be able to do with generics, and that would be helpful in maintenance. I'm guessing that I'm just not phrasing my search correctly. I know that these parameters are used at compile time, so maybe the only way to do something like this is to extend the compiler?

Can anyone give me some guidance on this? If I have to define the generic type parameters over and over again because that's just how it's done, that's fine with me; I'd just like to know what's possible. If the only solution is to extend the compiler, that's far more work than is worthwhile to put in.

Thanks!

Comment: No, you can't really do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't quite do what you're looking for, but you can get close.

You can create an intermediate interface. It may look like the following:

```java
interface AB implements A, B {}
```

You then implement this intermediate interface from the relevant classes:

```java
class Foo implements AB {
...
}
etc
```

And you can then do:

```java
public static <T extends AB> void method1() {}
public static <T extends AB> void method2() {}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely something worth trying!

Answer (score 0):

Do the methods have to be static?

If not, and the methods are related you could create a wrapper class to reduce duplicating code. This would simply look like:

```java
public class GenericWrapper<T extends A & B> {
    public void method1(T t1, T t2) {
        // Your code here. The parameters to this method could be anything.
    }
    public void method2(T t) {}
}
```

You then can reference the generic type T in method1 and method2. The Wrapper class may even suite well as a nested class.

To call the methods it would look something like:

```java
GenericWrapper<MyClass> wrapper = new GenericWrapper<MyClass>();

wrapper.method1(new MyClass(), new MyClass());
wrapper.method2(new MyClass());
```

The above is using the example parameters to the methods, in reality they may be anything.

Note this solution only works if the functions are not required to be static.

Comment: Thank you! I had an idea to do a wrapper, but I wasn't quite sure how to manage it with generics.

Comment: And actually, out of curiosity, what would go wrong if the methods were static? I do have some static methods that could benefit from this, if it worked.

Comment: @jsrc..programmer Good question, you would encounter a compilation error, as T is non-static, and therefore you would be referencing a non-static field in a static context which is not allowed. Also if either of the solutions I posted fit your question, do you mind marking it as correct?